# Desirability of mixed architecture software

Tags: compilation, cpu-architecture, build, architecture, native

Under what conditions can native code compiled for different architectures cooperate on the same operating system? When exactly is such mixing desirable?

Can, say 32 bit code run within a predominantly 64 bit process or do processes have to be pure?

I've been working on a Linux building and packaging system. My build targets are distinguished by an architecture (e.g., x86_64-gnu_linux ) and a variant (release, debug, something else) and for the packaging part, I've been operating under the simplifying assumption that no package can mixes architectures or depends on code built for a different target.
What exactly am I losing with this simplification?

Is it ever desirable to have a mixed architecture package assuming you have all the source code and it can compile for the native target?

Comment: Interesting question, but I fear it is off topic for [su].

Comment: @DavidPostill Where do you think it belongs?

Comment: I would guess [so] but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Definitely Stack Overflow. Voted to migrate this to SO.

Comment: I could imagine building some part of a system for the x32 ABI and another part (that needs a larger address space) for the usual x86-64 ABI.  Depending on how the parts communicate, a 32bit helper program could satisfy the dependency of a 64bit program.  But not a 32bit library for a 64bit program.

Comment: Within a single process, though, it's technically possible to change between long mode and compat mode, but I don't think anyone would do that, because there's no portable way to do it.  It's more plausible to have some threads use the regular 64bit ABI and some other threads use the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).  The CPU is in long mode for both those ABIs, though.  It's not really that plausible since x32 uses different libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, without using any hacks, a 32-bit shared library cannot be loaded in a 64-bit process. Conversely, a 64-bit library cannot be loaded in a 32-bit process. In other words, processes are pure; they are either 32-bit or 64-bit. Although it's technically possible to design a Linux OS that supports hybrid processes, but I don't think there are any such Linux distros.

When there is a need to interoperate 32-bit and 64-bit binaries, they should be run in different processes and then they can interoperate through some inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism.

So if you think it's possible it have multiple main executable files in the same package, then it is possible (although not common) to have binaries of different bit widths that are designed to interact through IPC in the same package. But even in such cases, there might be a single main executable (either 32-bit or 64-bit) that constitutes the starting point of the whole application. That executable would be responsible for launching other 32-bit or 64-bit processes. A package that contains all of these executables can be described solely by the architecture of that main executable, disregarding the target architectures of any other executables in the package. Doing something like that is reasonable.